# What is the proof of the formula for $\delta(g(x))$?

Tags: dirac-delta

Consider a function $g(x)$ such that the delta-function is given by $\delta(g(x))$, with $g(x)=0$ at $x_i$. Then we have that $$\sum_i=\frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|g(x_i)|}.$$

Can someone suggest me a page with a good proof or show me the proof themselves? Thanks.